# Is "rogamur ab eo ut veniamus" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar-identification

It is grammatically correct if I turn any Main active verb in the Indirect commands into passive ones?

Active - rogat nos ut veniamus - He asks us to come.

Passive - " rogamur ab eo ut veniamus " ?  - we are asked by him to come ?

Active - te rogabit ne venias - he will ask you not to come

Passive - " rogaberis ab eo ne venias " ? - you will be asked by him not to come ?

- Should I turn the subordinate verb into passive too? If so what the subordinate verb must agreed?

If you give any example than this it would be nice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using *rogare* or another transitive verb (that is, a verb that takes an accusative direct object), then yes, you can turn the main clause passive, exactly as you've done. All four of your Latin sentences are perfectly correct.

However, note that some *intransitive* verbs can also introduce indirect commands, such as *imperare* and *persuadere*. In these cases, to turn the main clause passive, you'd have to use an 'impersonal passive.' For example, *(nobis) imperat ut veniamus* would become *(nobis) ab eo imperatur ut veniamus*. (Literally, this means 'There is an ordering by him [of us] that we come'; practically speaking, though, the English meaning is 'We are ordered by him to come.')

You could turn the subordinate clauses passive too, if you wanted. However, for your specific examples, you would once again have to use an impersonal passive, because the verb *venire* is intransitive. In this case, the subordinate clause *ut veniamus* would become *ut a nobis veniatur*. Still, if you changed both clauses to passive voice in this way, the resulting sentence, *rogamur ab eo ut a nobis veniatur*, would be as clunky in Latin as the literal translation, 'We are asked by him that there be a coming by us,' is in English.

Comment: You point out that _imperare_ is an _intransitive_ verb but the example you give _nobis imperat ut veniamus_ can be claimed to involve a _transitive_ use of this verb (i.e., the direct object is the subordinate clause introduced by _ut_ : e.g., cf. the transitive use of _imperare_ selecting an _ut_ clause as its internal argument in http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/impero ). So note that it can be a bit confusing to say that your example _nobis ab eo imperatur ut veniamus_ is an impersonal passive (cf. _**Hoc** nobis ab eo imperatur_).

Comment: @Mitomino: In " nobis imperat ut veniamus" is the direct object "the order"? The literal translation of "impero" = "I-give-an-order-to" + dative. Analysis: "He (subject) gives (verb) an order (direct object) to us ([dative] indirect-object). The subordinate clause, "ut veniamus", is, then, a secondary indirect object? Thus in "nobis ab eo imperatur ut veniamus" = "It (subject) is ordered (the order is given) by him (direct object) to us that we come." In "hoc nobis ab eo imperatur." = "This is ordered (this order is given) by him to us.", where "this (order)" becomes the subject.

Comment: @tony, Although the verb imperare has a dative object to describe the person that the order is issued to, it can also take an explicit accusative direct object, contrary to what I say in my answer. For example, when a general orders a local town to supply him with troops, it can be phrased as 'He (nom. subect) ordered (imperavit) troops (acc. direct object) from them (dat. indirect object).' In a sentence like nobis imperat ut veniamus, the ut veniamus clause is filling the role of direct object. At some point, I need to update my answer to correct the inaccuracy that imperare is intransitive.