# Can a gerund introduce a subordinate clause?

Tags: classical-latin, subordinate-clause, gerund

Reading [this recent question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14873/is-rogamur-ab-eo-ut-veniamus-grammatically-correct) about whether the main verb introducing a purpose clause with *ut* can be in the passive voice, I thought about writing an answer that basically said: The main verb can be everything you want. It can be in the subjunctive mood, it can be an imperative, a participle, an infinitive, a supine in *-um*. OK, it cannot be a supine in *-u*, I guess. Those are terribly limited anyway.

But then I became unsure: Can it be a gerund? Can I say, for example:

> Ars rogandi ut pater nobis det pecuniam.
> *The art of asking that our father give us money.*

More generally, can a gerund introduce any subordinate clause?

> Calliditas in cognoscendo qui sit dux Gallorum.
> *Shrewdness in realizing who is the leader of the Gauls.*

I looked around and did not find much information. For example, Allen & Greenough's grammar is [not very forthcoming](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive) on this matter. I also looked for examples on Google Books, and I *did* find a few constructions like this, but they were all Neo-Latin.

Is this allowed in Classical Latin?

Comment: Interesting question! Cf. Joonas's related one: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/when-can-the-gerund-take-an-object In light of cnread’s answer, I was wondering **why** there is a contrast between your second exemple (see cnread’s examples below) and the fact that there seem to be no attested examples of the construction "IN + gerund + **accusative** object" in Classical Latin (cf. my answer to Joonas’s post). Perhaps examples like these involve a case of a neutralization of the gerund/gerundive distinction. The topic of when gerunds can take objects is very complex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has been my experience that gerunds can pretty freely introduce subordinate clauses.

For example, in Livy, *Ab urbe condita* 3.39.2, the ablative of the gerund introduces an indirect command (as in your first example):

> *L. Valerium Potitum proditum memoriae est post relationem Ap. Claudi, priusquam ordine sententiae rogarentur, **postulando ut de re publica liceret dicere**, prohibentibus minaciter decemviris proditurum se ad plebem denuntiantem, tumultum excivisse.*
>
> It's a matter of record that, after Appius Claudius had made his motion but before the senators were asked for comments in order, L. Valerius Potitus raised an uproar **by demanding that it be permitted to speak about the political situation**, proclaiming that he would go before the *plebs* when the decemvirs blocked him with threats.

In Cicero, *Tusculanae disputationes* 5.68, *in* + the ablative of the gerund introduces an indirect question (as in your second example):

> *ex quo triplex ille animi fetus existet, unus in cognitione rerum positus et in explicatione naturae, alter in discriptione expetendarum fugiendarumque rerum ne vivendi, tertius **in iudicando, quid cuique rei sit consequens quid repugnans**, in quo inest omnis cum subtilitas disserendi, tum veritas iudicandi.*
>
> From this will arise a threefold production of the mind, one of which lies in a knowledge of things and in an explanation of nature; the second in the definition of the things that should be sought and avoided, and in a principle of living well; and the third **in judging what consistency, what inconsistency each thing has**, which contains not only all skillfulness of forming an argument but also accuracy of judgment.

In Pliny the Younger, *Epistulae* 9.27.2, the genitive of the gerund introduces an indirect question:

> *tantus **audiendi quae fecerint** pudor, quibus nullus faciendi quae audire erubescunt.*
>
> So great is the shame that people have **of hearing what they did**, though they had no shame of doing the things that they now blush to hear about.

And in Cicero, *Epistulae ad Quintum fratrem* 1.1.30, *in* + the ablative of the gerund introduces an object clause.

> etenim si **in promerendo ut tibi tanti honores haberentur** quanti haud scio an nemini fuisti omnium diligentissimus, multo maiorem in his honoribus tuendis adhibere diligentiam debes.
>
> In fact, if you were most diligent of all **in earning that such great honors be paid to you** as perhaps have never been paid to anyone, you should apply all the greater diligence in protecting those honors.

---

Incidentally, with regard to your comment about supines in *u*, even that's possible. For example, in  Cicero, *Pro lege Manilia* 65, a supine introduces an indirect question:

> *difficile est **dictu**, Quirites, **quanto in odio simus** apud exteras nationes propter eorum quos ad eas per hos annos cum imperio misimus libidines et iniurias.*
>
> It's difficult **to say**, Quirites, **in what great hatred we are held** among foreign peoples because of the wantonness and injuries of those whom we have sent to them with *imperium* during recent years.

Really, then, for the question that you refer to, you would have been quite correct to answer, 'The main verb can be everything you want.'

Comment: In relation to your exemples from Cicero, involving “in + gerund + **sentential** object”, I was wondering why they are possible but the construction “in +gerund + **accusative** object” is not attested in Early & Classical Latin (according to Vester (1991). https://benjamins.com/catalog/slcs.21.21ves). Should one then posit that what we have here is a gerundival construction where the “nominal” subordinate clause can be replaced by an ablative pronoun? Or is it a case of a neutralization of the gerund/gerundive distinction?

Comment: @Mitomino. That's a very good question. Now that you've asked it, I find that I do tend to think of them as equivalent to in eō iudicandō and in eō promerendō (i.e., gerundival), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. These are exactly the sort of example I was looking for. Also, it's fascinating to see the supine used that way, although in hindsight, in *that* case if I had looked, I would easily have found examples at least for AcI constructions (e.g. Google search for "nefas est dictu"). The gerund examples I find much harder to Google for.

Comment: @Mitomino You may have pinpointed the reason for my uncertainty. The intuitive answer to my question ("is this allowed?") would be: "Sure, why not?" It was the restrictions on the use of gerunds that gave me pause.

Comment: [This answer has been nominated as one of the best answers of 2020.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/531/79)